# Could not find an overload for "init" that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I am also having this error when using `UIFont`:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold", size: 22.0)]
```

Someone has an idea how I can fix this ? I tried casting 22.0 to `CGFloat` with no effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because `UIFont` initialisation can fail and nil will be returned. Try:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold", size: 22.0) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: font]
}
```